# Dynamic jquerymobile colum toggle not getting refreshed

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile 1.3 -> column toggle Table widget.
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/table-column-toggle/

I am creating the rows and columns dynamically. When I do this, the column toggle mode doesn't work. If I hardcode the data, it works. What could be wrong?

I am also refreshing as suggested in their documentation.

```
$( "#myTable" ).table-columntoggle( "refresh" );
```

My Javascript code is straight forward.

```
var tBody = document.getElementById('idTBody');
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.innerHTML = "Some string";
tr.appendChild(td);
tBody.appendChild(tr);
```

idTBody is an id assigned to Tbody tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is a known bug in jquerymobile in 1.3.0 and will be fixed in 1.3.1.
Here's the link --> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5640 and here is the tracker link -->https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5570